# Is there a way to exclude a rule and don't affect my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this rule in my css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

And I have this jquery effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#entries").hide(400);
        $("#message").show(400);
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#message").hide(400);
        $("#entries").show(400);
    });
});
```

When I press "#hide", the show and hide effect for **#entries** and **#message** is ruined due to the transition. Is there a way to exclude the rule and have no affect only for the jQuery show / hide?

Comment: You could specifically reset the transition properties before doing hide/show ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your rule for:

```
*:not(#message):not(#entries) {
  /* your rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding `active` class from `css` rules ; add, remove `"active"` class during animations

css

```
   *:not(.active) {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    }
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elems = $("#entries, #message");
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        elems.addClass("active");
        $("#entries").hide(400);
        $("#message").show(400, function() {
          elems.removeClass("active")
        });
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        elems.addClass("active");
        $("#message").hide(400);
        $("#entries").show(400, function() {
          elems.removeClass("active")
        });
    });
```